# Python rock paper scissors score counter

Tags: python, counter

I am working on a rock paper scissors game. Everything seems to be working well except the win/loss/tie counter. I have looked at some of the other games people have posted on here and I still cannot get mine to work. I feel like I am soooooo close but I just can't get it! thanks for any help guys. this is my first time posting in here so I am sorry if I messed up the formatting.

I edited the code but still cannot get the program to recognize the counter without using global variables. at one point of my editing I managed to get it to count everything as a tie... i dont know how and I lost it somewhere along my editing. lol. -thanks again everyone!

here is what I get when I run the program:

```
Prepare to battle in a game of paper, rock, scissors!
Please input the correct number according
to the object you want to choose.
Select rock(1), paper(2), or scissors(3): 1
Computer chose PAPER .
You chose ROCK .
You lose!
Play again? Enter 'y' for yes or 'n' for no. y
Prepare to battle in a game of paper, rock, scissors!
Please input the correct number according
to the object you want to choose.
Select rock(1), paper(2), or scissors(3): 2
Computer chose PAPER .
You chose PAPER .
It's a tie!
Play again? Enter 'y' for yes or 'n' for no. y
Prepare to battle in a game of paper, rock, scissors!
Please input the correct number according
to the object you want to choose.
Select rock(1), paper(2), or scissors(3): 3
Computer chose SCISSORS .
You chose SCISSORS .
It's a tie!
Play again? Enter 'y' for yes or 'n' for no. n
Your total wins are 0 .
Your total losses are 0 .
Your total ties are 0 .
```

---

```
#import the library function "random" so that you can use it for computer 
#choice 
import random 

#define main 
def main(): 
    #assign win, lose, and tie to zero for tallying
    win = 0 
    lose = 0 
    tie = 0 

    #control loop with 'y' variable 
    play_again = 'y' 

    #start the game 
    while play_again == 'y': 
        #make a welcome message and give directions 
        print('Prepare to battle in a game of paper, rock, scissors!') 
        print('Please input the correct number according') 
        print('to the object you want to choose.') 

        #Get the player and computers choices and 
        #assign them to variables 
        computer_choice = get_computer_choice() 
        player_choice = get_player_choice() 

        #print choices 
        print('Computer chose', computer_choice, '.') 
        print('You chose', player_choice, '.') 

        #determine who won 
        winner_result(computer_choice, player_choice) 

        #ask the user if they want to play again 
        play_again = input("Play again? Enter 'y' for yes or 'n' for no. ") 

    #print results 
    print('Your total wins are', win, '.') 
    print('Your total losses are', lose, '.') 
    print('Your total ties are', tie, '.') 

#define computer choice 
def get_computer_choice(): 
    #use imported random function from library 
    choice = random.randint(1,3) 

    #assign what the computer chose to rock, paper, or scissors 
    if choice == 1: 
        choice = 'ROCK' 
    elif choice == 2: 
        choice = 'PAPER' 
    else: 
        choice = 'SCISSORS' 

    #return value 
    return choice 

#define player choice 
def get_player_choice(): 
    #assign input to variable by prompting user 
    choice = int(input("Select rock(1), paper(2), or scissors(3): ")) 

    #Detect invalid entry
    while choice != 1 and choice != 2 and choice != 3: 
        print('The valid numbers are rock(type in 1), paper(type in 2),') 
        print('or scissors(type in 3).') 
        choice = int(input('Enter a valid number please: ')) 

    #assign what the player chose based on entry 
    if choice == 1: 
        choice = 'ROCK' 
    elif choice == 2: 
        choice = 'PAPER' 
    else: 
        choice = 'SCISSORS' 

    #return value 
    return choice 

#determine the winner from the variables 
def winner_result(computer_choice, player_choice): 
    #if its a tie, add 1 to tie variable and display message 
    if computer_choice == player_choice:
        result = 'tie'
        print("It's a tie!")

    #if its a win, add to win tally and display message 
    elif computer_choice == 'SCISSORS' and player_choice == 'ROCK':
        result = 'win'
        print('ROCK crushes SCISSORS! You win!')
    elif computer_choice == 'PAPER' and player_choice == 'SCISSORS': 
        result = 'win'
        print('SCISSORS cut PAPER! You win!')
    elif computer_choice == 'ROCK' and player_choice == 'PAPER': 
        result = 'win'
        print('PAPER covers ROCK! You win!')

    #if it does not match any of the win criteria then add 1 to lose and 
    #display lose message 
    else: 
        result = 'lose'
        print('You lose!')

def result(winner_result,player_choice, computer_choice):

    # accumulate the appropriate winner of game total
    if result == 'win':
        win += 1
    elif result == 'lose':
        lose += 1
    else:
        tie += 1
    return result

main()
```

Comment: It looks like you are having some trouble pasting your code with indentation intact.  It's important that you fix this because your problem probably boils down to flow control, and indentation often affects flow control in Python.  It would also be good to be more explicit about what is going wrong with your current program -- what input you put in for testing, what output you expect, and what output you get.

Comment: Indentation ALWAYS affects flow control in python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `winner_result` function returns before it increments the win counters. If you remove all the `return` statements from it, the counters should be updated. The `return` statements aren't needed anyway because the `if/elif/else` structure ensures that only one of the possible outcomes will be executed.

As Junuxx says in a comment, you also need to assign values to the `winner_result` variable properly, i.e. `winner_result = 'win'` instead of `winner_result == 'win'`. I'd also rename the `winner_result` variable or the function, because it's confusing to have both use the same name.

And the `win/lose/tie` variables are currently local, which means that `main` and `winner_result` will have their own copies of these variables, so `main`'s values will always be zero. What you can do is make them global variables: Assign them to zero in the global scope (outside any function), and add the line `global win, lose, tie` inside the function `winner_result`.

Comment: `winner_result` also has a bunch of lines like `winner_result == 'win'` which have no effect; they should have a single `=` for assignment. And then there's the scope of `win/lose/tie`.

Comment: I think I fixed the formatting finally. I will give that a try by removing the returns. thanks!

Comment: @Junuxx Good spotting, I added this to the answer.

Comment: thanks guys I am still working on it. I am not to use global variables for for the counter. I will try assigning winner_result variables and modifying from there. -thanks!

Comment: I have edited the code and included what I get when I run the program. I am still having an issue getting it to go without the global variable though. I am still plugging away at it but any more help would be appreciated!

Comment: @user1783570: At the end of `winner_result`, add `return result`. Then use `result = winner_result(computer_choice, player_choice)` in `main` and use that value to update `win/lose/tie`.

Comment: I think i am putting the result = winner_result(computer_choice, player_choice) in the wrong location because now I am getting 'computer_choice' is not defined or computer_choice is refernced before assignment. sorry I am still not getting this I have been working on this thing for hours!!! hopefully once i figure it out it will be easy to create counters on other programs after this.

Comment: @user1783570: The same place where you call `winner_result` now, right below `#determine who won`! Eventually it will definitely become easier, and you'll learn that it's best to use a class and instance variables for things like this. But for now this should do :)

Comment: thanks junuxx. I was finally able to figure it out. thanks everyone else for the help as well. :)

Answer (score 0):

Obviously been a few years since this question was answered but it came up while I was looking the same info. Here's my code if anyone is interested.

```
#! usr/bin/python3
import random


def game():

    computer_count = 0
    user_count = 0

    while True:
        base_choice = ['scissors', 'paper', 'rock']
        computer_choice = random.choice(base_choice)

        user_choice = input('(scissors, paper, rock) Type your choice: ').strip().lower()
        print()
        computer_wins = 'The computer wins!'
        you_win = 'You win!'

        print(f'You played {user_choice}, the computer played {computer_choice}')
        if user_choice == 'scissors' and computer_choice == 'rock' or \
           user_choice == 'paper' and computer_choice == 'scissors' or \
           user_choice == 'rock' and computer_choice == 'paper':
            print(computer_wins)
            computer_count += 1

        elif user_choice == 'rock' and computer_choice == 'scissors' or \
            user_choice == 'scissors' and computer_choice == 'paper' or \
                user_choice == 'paper' and computer_choice == 'rock':
                print(you_win)
                user_count += 1

        else:
            if user_choice == computer_choice:
                print('Its a draw!')
                computer_count += 1
                user_count += 1

        print(f'Computer: {computer_count} - You: {user_count}')
        print()


game()
```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do the same project, and I have found a solution that works well for me.

```py
from random import randint

win_count = 0
lose_count = 0
tie_count = 0

# create a list of play options
t = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"]

# assign a random play to the computer
computer = t[randint(0, 2)]

# set player to false
player = False

print()
print("To stop playing type stop at any time.")
print()
while player == False:
    # set player to True
    player = input("Rock, Paper or Scissors? ")
    if player.lower() == "stop":
        print()
        print(
            f"Thanks for playing! Your final record was {win_count}-{lose_count}-{tie_count}")
        print()
        break
    if player.title() == computer:
        print()
        print("Tie!")
        tie_count += 1
        print()
    elif player.title() == "Rock":
        if computer == "Paper":
            print()
            print(f"You lose. {computer} covers {player.title()}.")
            lose_count += 1
            print()
        else:
            print()
            print(f"You win! {player.title()} smashes {computer}.")
            win_count += 1
            print()
    elif player.title() == "Paper":
        if computer == "Scissors":
            print()
            print(f"You lose. {computer} cuts {player.title()}.")
            lose_count += 1
            print()
        else:
            print()
            print(f"You win!, {player.title()} covers {computer}.")
            win_count += 1
            print()
    elif player.title() == ("Scissors"):
        if computer == "Rock":
            print()
            print(f"You lose. {computer} smashes {player.title()}.")
            lose_count += 1
            print()
        else:
            print()
            print(f"You win! {player.title()} cuts {computer}.")
            win_count += 1
            print()
    else:
        print()
        print("Sorry, we couldn't understand that.")
        print()
# player was set to True, but we want it to be false to continue loop
print(f"Your record is {win_count}-{lose_count}-{tie_count}")
print()
player = False
computer = t[randint(0, 2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You were really soooooo close, that Your feeling is right. In Python the variables inside a function are not accessible outside the function. You need to call the result function too.

You can use global declaration in the result function, it makes the win, lose and tie variables accessible outside the function:

```
#rename the function, because it got a variable name
def saveResult(result):
    global win, lose, tie

    # accumulate the appropriate winner of game total
    if result == 'win':
        win += 1
    elif result == 'lose':
        lose += 1
    else:
        tie += 1
```

Then call the saveResult function in the winner_result function:

```
def winner_result(computer_choice, player_choice): 
    #if its a tie, add 1 to tie variable and display message 
    if computer_choice == player_choice:
        result = 'tie'
        print("It's a tie!")

    #if its a win, add to win tally and display message 
    elif computer_choice == 'SCISSORS' and player_choice == 'ROCK':
        result = 'win'
        print('ROCK crushes SCISSORS! You win!')
    elif computer_choice == 'PAPER' and player_choice == 'SCISSORS': 
        result = 'win'
        print('SCISSORS cut PAPER! You win!')
    elif computer_choice == 'ROCK' and player_choice == 'PAPER': 
        result = 'win'
        print('PAPER covers ROCK! You win!')

    #if it does not match any of the win criteria then add 1 to lose and 
    #display lose message 
    else: 
        result = 'lose'
        print('You lose!')
    
    #calling the saveResult function to save the score
    saveResult(result)
```

If You are interested, I also made a rock, paper, scissors game in Python:

```
import random

options = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]    
winners = {"rock": "scissors", "paper": "rock", "scissors": "paper"}
score = [0, 0]

def winner(you, computer):
    global score
    if you == computer:
        return "Tie!"
    if winners[you] == computer:
        score[0] += 1
        return "You won!"
    else:
        score[1] += 1
        return "Computer won!"
    
print("Welcome!")
print("Type \"new\" to begin new game, or type \"quit\" to quit.\n")

while True:
    yourInput = input("Rock, paper or scissors: ")
    yourInput = yourInput.lower()
    if yourInput == "quit":
        break
    elif yourInput == "new":
        score = [0, 0]
    elif yourInput not in options:
        print("Invalid input.")
    else:
        computer = random.choice(options)
        output = winner(yourInput, computer)

        print("\n" + output)
        print("You: " + yourInput)
        print("Computer: " + computer + "\n")
        print("Score: " + str(score[0]) + " - " + str(score[1]) + "\n")
```

Answer (score -1):

This works (kinda)
there are many issues with the code at the top of the page.
Firstly, Scoring doesn't work.
Secondly, nothing is indented meaning that nothing inside of the other def functions will work.
Thirdly, The other def functions are referred to in the first def main statement which causes Python to show an invalid syntax due to Python not knowing the other functions as they were referred to before they were introduced to python.

Comment: Hello, your answer could be improved by better formatting and more specific ("Scoring doesn't work)" explanations. Thank you.